ASReml-R GBLUP cannot find predict labels
*    tmf <- asreml(fixed = oil ~ 1, random = ~ vm(line_code, grm_train), maxiter = 100, data = temp_train)
    pred <- predict.asreml(tmf, classify = 'line_code')
[ASReml Version 4.2 25/07/2024 16:01:13 Model fitted using the gamma parameterization. LogLik        Sigma2     DF     wall 1     -1247.260      4.257250    959   16:01:13     2     -1247.260      4.257249    959   16:01:13     3     -1247.260      4.257245    959   16:01:13     Error in asreml(fixed = oil ~ 1, random = ~vm(line_code, grm_train), data = temp_train,  :  Cannot find predict labels for line_code *
Online guides use this approach with no problems. If I have 'line_code' as a random effect but not within vm() everything works, but once I use a genomic relationship matrix, I get the above error.
Thank you.
Tried to use the predict function within asreml to predict the value of random effects using a genomic relationship matrix.
